# PHP/Sql - Trying to get the max id of a row according to a certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get from a Sql table the row's id number with a certain conditions.

Let's say I have the next tabble -

```
     id           sender           touser         message
    ----------------------------------------------------
    1            User1            User2           Hi
    2            User2            User1           Hello
    3            User3            User1           How r u
    4            User1            User3           r u there?
    5            User1            User2           Hey
    6            User2            User3           Hey
```

So I would like to get the largest id row number that have User1 as a sender and User2 as the to user., Meaning i would like to get the number 5.

In order to do so I've used the next php code -

```
$query = "SELECT sender, touser, max(id) as latest_id FROM messages WHERE sender = :sender, touser = :touser LIMIT 1 ";

$query_params = array(
    ':sender' => $_POST['sender'],
    ':touser' => $_POST['touser']
);

  try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add post!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$row = $stmt->fetch();
$resultid = $row['id'];

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = $resultid;
echo json_encode($response);
```

The thing is that the code gets into the catch, and I'm getting the - Database Error. Couldn't add post! - response all the time.

So what am I doing wrong over here?

I guess that my SELECT statement is causing the problem.

Any ideas how can i get the result that i want?

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE sender = :sender, touser = :touser
```

should be

```
WHERE sender = :sender AND touser = :touser
```

or

```
WHERE sender = :sender OR touser = :touser

AND - matching both 
OR - Matching just one of them
```

Comment: Well that got me out of the error - but now I've got new problem - it says that Undefined index: id at the - $resultid = $row['id']; - What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: U have an alias as latest_id u need to use that instead of id as `$resultid = $row['latest_id'];`

Comment: Does this - 'latest_id - will give me the last id in the whole DB (in my example is 6) or the last id of my request - in my example it should be 5?

Comment: what is the val of sender and touser u are sending and are u using AND in the query ? or using  `WHERE sender = :sender OR touser = :touser` ?

Comment: I'm using this line -  $query = "SELECT groupname, groupopener, max(id) as latest_id FROM groupmessages WHERE groupname = :groupname AND groupopener = :groupopener LIMIT 1 "; - So what I'm wondring is whatever it will get me the last id in the whole dbor maybe the last id of what i requested?

Comment: check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d0bd/4 this should return the data as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT sender, touser, max(id) as latest_id 
FROM messages 
WHERE sender = :sender AND touser = :touser 
GROUP BY sender,touser 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$query = "SELECT sender, touser, max(id) as latest_id FROM messages WHERE sender = :sender, touser = :touser LIMIT 1 ";
```

To

`$query = "SELECT sender, touser, max(id) as latest_id FROM messages WHERE sender = :sender AND touser = :touser LIMIT 1 ";`